# How to check expiry date of Pre-signed url in AWS S3 link?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working in AWS S3 with upload and download.  I have generated Pre signed URL with expiry date.  It is working fine.  Here i am going to delete files in S3 after expired that is no longer needed.

I had a link.  How to check the link is expired or not using C#?

Any one assist me to handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. The pre-signed URL is validated when the API request is received by AWS but I think there is no API call to describe the properties of temporary keys / pre-signed URLs. Can't you just keep a note of the expiry time requested when the URL was created?

Comment: Sure, i'll try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check pre-signed URL already expired.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(awsUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden){}
```